# Remove BluetoothLE Peripheral from UITableView when Out Of Range

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-bluetooth

I have an ios app that scans for BluetoothLE peripherals. When it discovers them it adds them to my UITableView as a custom cell (PeripheralCell). When the iPhone discovers it again, it auto updates the RSSI value in the UITableView.

The problem I have is that when the BluetoothLE peripheral goes out of range, it stays on my UITableView. How can I have it update automatically and REMOVE the peripheral from my table when it doesn't find the BLE peripheral after a period of time... say 1.5 seconds?

```
 /**
 Called when scanner finds device
 First checks if it exists, if not then insert new device
 */
- (void) centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{

    BOOL (^test)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop);
    test = ^ (id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
        if([[[obj peripheral] name] compare:peripheral.name] == NSOrderedSame)
            return YES;
        return NO;
    };

    PeripheralCell* pcell; //custom UITableViewCell
    NSUInteger t=[peripherals indexOfObjectPassingTest:test];
    if(t!= NSNotFound)
    {
        pcell=[peripherals objectAtIndex:t];
        pcell.peripheral=peripheral;
        pcell.rssi=RSSI;
        [scanResult reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:t inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }else{
        pcell=[[PeripheralCell alloc] init];
        [peripherals addObject: pcell];
        pcell.peripheral=peripheral;
        pcell.rssi=RSSI;
        [scanResult insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:[peripherals count]-1 inSection:0]] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
    }

}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if(peripherals==nil)
        return 0;
    return [peripherals count];
}

/**
 Configures the list of found peripherals in the table view
 */
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"foundDevice";

    PeripheralCell *cell = [scanResult dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    // Configure the cell.
    PeripheralCell *pcell=[peripherals objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
    cell.peripheralTitleLabel.text = [pcell.peripheral name];
    cell.rssiLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RSSI %d",[pcell.rssi intValue]];
    //self.colorNames objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: you can make NSTimer to check all the device every 1.5s. when some disappeared remove them from peripherals and then reloadData

Comment: Can you be more specific as to how I could accomplish this in code? Would "reload data" cause my cells to be removed and then re-added causing a shift in their order or the screen to flash? Thank you!!

Comment: reloadData is a member function of UITableView.it will reload all the cells according to your peripherals array. if the order is the same in your array. there is no shift.it's better when there is some change in your array, you use reloadData.

Comment: Could I create an NSTimer for EVERY peripheral that is discovered and set it to 1.5s. Then, when it is re-discovered, reset the time back to 1.5s. If the time expires, then that item would be removed. Would that be too many NSTimers? Could be 10 or more.

Comment: One timer is enough. Use this timer to check the peripherals one by one. i think you can set time interval a bit longer.